# Room error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type

Tags: java, android, android-room

I don't get it, I though this is the way to get the id of newly inserted row.

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface AlarmDao {

    .....

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insertAll(AlarmEntity...alarms); //used long instead of void
}
```

**ENTITY**

```
@Entity(tableName = "tb_alarm")
public class AlarmEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    ...

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

but building is failed and I'm getting error which is pointing into my `Dao` class and the error is:

> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

What did I missed about it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
AlarmEntity...alarms
```

this translates in multiple inserts. So the return type should be a `List<Long>` or a `long[]`, and it makes sense. If you pass two items you will get two id, one for each newly inserted row.

If you want to insert only 1 item at time, remove the `varargs` (`...`). EG

```
@Insert
long insert(AlarmEntity alarms);
```

Comment: I forgot about the 3 dots, embarrassing.

Answer (score 31):

If anyone is having this issue in December 2021, I just fixed my problem and it may the same as yours.

As it is, kotlin 1.6.0 has been officially rolled out. However, with the stable 2.3.0 release of Room it doesn't include the dependencies to work with this updated kotlin.

What I did was update my room to 2.4.0-rc01 and that solved my problem!

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me! You solved my problem.

Comment: my pleasure, friend :)

Comment: You've saved my day!

Comment: If everyone gets a similar issue for Kotlin `1.7`, just update to Room `2.4.3`: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_243_3

Comment: thank you so much this error of mine was not getting resolved since 2 dasys

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was getting the same error because of the **vararg**. After removing it, the error vanished.

Wrong

```
@Insert
suspend fun insert(vararg client: Client): Long
```

Correct

```
@Insert
suspend fun insert(client: Client): Long
```

Answer (score 6):

Following the documentaion if the `@Insert` method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a `long`, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return `long[]` or `List<Long>` instead.
in your case you have a list as paramater, you should return `long[]` or `List<Long>`
Source : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#java

Answer (score 4):

From [Accessing data using Room DAOs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience):

> If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.

Change the return type of `insertAll ()` to long[] or List

Answer (score 4):

I have none of the above problem, getting same error for simple method like  this

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun upsert(user: User): Long
```

I fixed the issue by updating the room library to the latest version available.
In my case, the latest version was  2.3.0, so I changed to:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your build.gradle(project level) dependencies classpath of

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0`

to

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31`

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"    
    // Downgrade in your scenario. It will be 1.6.0, please change this to 1.5.31.
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'   
}
```

Comment: why? a reference to the reason behind this downgrade would be so nice.

Answer (score 0):

### in kotlin version 1.9.22

I have tried **room** versions `2.3.0` , `2.4.2`, `2.4.2`, `2.5.2` and still get the same **error** that I cannot handle insert return type.

**Solution:**
Use room version `2.6.0` and you get solved.

Answer (score -1):

For my case i just downgraded Kotlin plugin version from `1.7.10` to `1.6.20`, you should try to downgrade or upgrade your version (not like my version) but as you see it should be.


from:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

to:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}
```